# Let, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, then $||\textrm{diag}(A)||_{\infty} \le ||A||_{2} $.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

We let, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. We have that,
$$||Ae_{j}||_{2} = ||a_{j}||_{2}, ~ ~ j \in [1,n].$$
Where $a_j$ denotes the $j $'th column of $A$. So  we have that,
$$ a_{j,j} \le ||a_j||_{2}.$$
Hence,
$$||\textrm{diag}(A)||_{\infty} \le ||A||_{2}. $$

Does my proof look good? Thank you!

Comment: @TobbiasRieper, yes.

Comment: Almost. You need $|a_{jj}|\le\|a_j\|_2$ rather than $a_{jj}\le\|a_j\|_2$.

Comment: What $\| A\|_2$ mean, the operator norm?